# Can we extract number from string and multiply them

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to make a program that can extract all numbers from string and multiply them like string is "multiply 30 and 50", then program should able to remove spaces and alphabets and multiply remaining numbers, numbers can be more then 2, can you please tell me how can i do it

```
test = '*'.join(c for c in "multiply 30 and 50" if c.isdigit())
print(f'answer is {test}')
```

The result should be 1500

Comment: If the commands are not restricted with just math, you are basically asking compiler/interpreter theory. If you want to, try splitting the words by spaces, check if it is a number or text using string methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for this:

```
from re import compile as recompile

numbers = recompile(r'\d+')
```

You can then use `reduce` and `mul` to multiply the digits, like:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

query = 'multiply 30 and 50'
result = reduce(mul, map(int, numbers.findall(query)))
```

This then gives us:

```
>>> result
1500
```

This of course does not take into acount the "*multiply ... and ...*" part, so if it was "*subtract 5 from 10*", it would still return `50`.

If you want to make a more advanced system, that thus does not just looks for numbers in the string, you should implement a [*parser* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser), for example with a [*compiler-compiler* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your attempted approach, but working:

```
s = 'multiply 5 by 10'
import re
s = '*'.join(re.findall('\d+',s))
print(f'{eval(s)}')
```